# Get the CGRect frame of the inner contentView of a UINavigationController during or before loadView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Apple's docs say:

```
Note: Because the amount of space available for the custom view can vary
(depending on the size of the other navigation views), your custom view’s
autoresizingMask property should be set to have a flexible width and height.
Before displaying your view, the navigation controller automatically
positions and sizes it to fit the available space.
```

That's great, except ... I need to know the size UINavController will use *BEFORE* the view is added to the frame, because the content I'll be displaying is different depending on the size.

This is inside the "loadView" method of a UIViewController that's being added to the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, technically you shouldn't be sizing your subviews in the `loadView` method.  I don't use nibs, and in almost all of my view controllers the `loadView` is really small: `self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];`.  Then, in `viewDidLoad` I add all my subviews to `self.view`.  Finally, I do all of my resizing in `viewWillAppear`, because at that point `self.view` will be the appropriate size.

If you must size views in the `loadView` method, you'll have to calculate out the dimensions manually...i.e: find out the orientation of the device (`self.interfaceOrientation`) determine the screen size, subtract out whatever other elements you think are on screen (like a Navigation bar, etc).  But this method is not recommended.

Comment: I found no difference between loadView/viewDidLoad (which is where Apple specifically says you should setup views - not viewWillAppear) - is there something nasty I'm missing? I like your idea that I could ignore Apple and use viewWillAppear instead, but from memory there's some resizing that can still happen after viewWillAppear (edge cases, not sure if it's bugs in UIKit - maybe fixed by now anyway)

Comment: Yeah, you can initialize your views and create your view hierarchy in the 'viewDidLoad'.  You arrange/layout your views in 'viewDidAppear'.  You want to do this because if you change your code to use nibs, all setting up your IBOutlets is done in viewDidLoad.  To be honest, I don't think you have to use viewDidLoad, but it follows the recommended pattern (and if Apple changes something later, you could be screwed).  I believe the dimensions in 'viewWillAppear' should be final...until a screen rotation, of course.

Comment: Also, you want your layout in `viewWillAppear` because if another view controller is being displayed (if it were pushed in a UINav controller, for example) your view controller won't get rotation events.  So if the orient was portrait when the VC view disappeared, and then landscape when the VC view appears again, the only way you can arrange your views appropriately is in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Confirmed: viewDidLoad definitely doesn't get access to the real frame size, but viewWillAppear definitely does.

Comment: UNaccepted this answer, because it appears that it's only sometimes correct. I have a new project - only 10 lines of code - and self.view.frame is always zero in viewWillAppear *unless* you use Apple's default loadView implementation. There is something magical in their implementation that DOES NOT happen if you use "self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];" (confirmed by commenting-out the 1-line loadView method - comment it out, and Apple provides a self.view.frame; add it back in, Apple does not)

Comment: NB: on my much larger project, this seemed to work fine - although as noted I thought it had (at one point) not worked. It seems that it's only a "sometimes works" approach :(

Comment: More testing: this approach works *if you're adding to a UINavigationController* - but it breaks your code if you ever add it to a non-nav-controller. So ... I've started a new question to answer "how do you write loadView so that it always works, rather than sometimes works" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803931/correct-loadview-implementation

Answer (score 1):

Since the view hierarchy inside a navigation controller is not documented, there is probably no reliable way to get this information.

You would have to:

1. Either ask `self.navigationController.view` for its bounds and manually subtract the room that is occupied by the navigation bar (if `navigationBarHidden` is `NO`) and the toolbar (if `toolbarHidden` is `NO`),
2. Or manually traverse the subviews of `self.navigationController.view` and try to identify the content view (if such a thing exists) or the space the other views occupy.

Both solutions rely on internals that could change in future iOS releases and are therefore far from optimal. Can't you wait until `viewDidLoad` for the decision what content to display?

Comment: I might have a bug, but viewDidLoad was still coming in BEFORE UINavigationController resized the view ... I'll check

Comment: That might be true, I'm not sure. In that case, `viewDid/WillLayoutSubviews` might be the best place.

Answer (score 0):

What about using KVO for viewController.view.frame property?

Comment: If I understand correctly ... I'd put all my view-creation code inside a KVO listener, and add an extra BOOl to the class to remember whether I've already set up the views, so it doesnt go wrong every time there's any kind of resize?

Comment: Do you have states for the UI of your VC? Is it a state machine? You may just set a correct state in observer method + also override the setState: method, where change UI.